# How to filter records from a Datatable from a given range of date for a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a single date field `createdDate` in my datatable. and the 2 drop downs which gives starting date and end date. what I want to do is after clicikng on a button the records should get filtered out.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
   <input type="date" class = "createdDateFilter" id="createdDateFrom" name="createdDateFrom">
</div>
                                
                                
<label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="createdDateTo">Created Date(To)</label>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <input type="date" class = "createdDateFilter" id="createdDateTo" name="createdDateTo">
 </div>

<div class="buttons">
   <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="search" type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
```

My JS file:

```
// This will update the start date
$("#createdDateFrom").change(function () {
    // currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentdate.getDate() + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear();
    createdDateFrom = new Date($(this).val());

});
// This will update the end date
$("#createdDateTo").change(function () {
    createdDateTo = new Date($(this).val());
});
```

I am pretty much blank ahead of this. Is it even possible? I am aware of the search input filters for every column but I want a separate button. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just seen this thread on StackOverflow which could help you

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

He created a class, that you have to copy one of his function in your code like this :

```
function inRange(d,start,end) {
   return (
        isFinite(d=this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(start=this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
        isFinite(end=this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
        start <= d && d <= end :
        NaN
    );
}
```

So according to his anwser, you can use it in filter function.

You'll have to get your datas array in var.

Suppose we have

```
let arr = [/*your datas*/]
```

You can simply return the filter result applied on 'arr'

```
function getOnlyInRangeDateItems(arr, startDate, endDate) {
    return arr.filter(item => inRange(item.createdDate, startDate, endDate))
}
```

Finally, just call it :

```
let date1 = new Date($("#createdDateFrom").val())
let date2 = new Date($("#createdDateTo").val())

let datasInRange = getOnlyInRangeDateItems(arr, date1, date2)
```